# Clearing content from a movieclip in a blank keyframe in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var loader:URLLoader;
var allWords:Array;
var thisWord:String;
var textContainer:MovieClip;
var textFields:Array;
var textStyle:TextFormat;
var underline:MovieClip;
var numCorrect:uint;
var totalLetters:uint;
var misses:uint;
var missesToLose:uint;

function initializeGame():void
{
loader = new URLLoader();
allWords = new Array();

textContainer = new MovieClip();
textFields = new Array();

textStyle = new TextFormat();

textStyle.font = "Courier New";
textStyle.size = 48;
textStyle.bold = true;
```

Hi All,

I have created this game and only added the beginning portion of the code. The entire code would be tedious to go through. I want to click a button and go to a clear keyframe, however when I test the movie the underline movieclip still shows. How can I clear the frame completely, do I have to removeChild for the movieclip? How do I do that? Is there a way to completely unload the SWF for this game after it is loaded? If so what code can I use?

Thanks

Comment: Complete newbie to this

Comment: anything you add to the screen via code, will have to be removed by code.  So if somewhere you are doing `addChild(textCOntainer)`,  you'll have to do `removeChild(textContainer)` when you want it to go away.

Comment: Can you show the part that makes stuff appear? Presumably you're adding stuff to the stage somewhere, right? The part you've shown doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Comment: you could remove everything with...  while(mc.numChildren > 0){mc.removeChildAt(0)};

Comment: mc.removeChildren() works too

Comment: Thanks guys I'll have a look